# CAT6 Cable crossover with Electric cable

Tags: wiring, cable-management

My CAT6 cable is running parallel to Electric cable in the floor.  Although it has a gap of 1 feet, but due to my room setup/requirement there are few places where both need to cross over (refer the diagram).

Will this setup cause any issue?

[image]

Comment: What type of "pipe" (conduit) is the electric cable inside, or is it just a plain cable in the wall?

Comment: Cross talk between power and ethernet can cause issues, but I think 12 inches is enough spacing. Since you plan to cross perpendicular, you'll be fine. Metal conduit won't hurt, but I don't know if it would help or if it would even matter.

Comment: What kind of pipe/conduit is the CAT6 running in?

Answer (score 3):

No. You'll be fine.

Compared to the frequencies modern Ethernet is operating at, home wiring might as well be DC, plus Ethernet has good common mode rejection that will deal with it anyway.

If this was massive data center or a high performance scientific installation you might have to think harder, but for a typical home or light commercial installation you don't have to worry about crosstalk with power wiring.

Comment: Agreed, you'll be fine. In fact, best practice when low-voltage cables need to cross over line voltage is at a 90 degree angle, which is what you are doing. Perfect.